# Switch form Next/Previous to post title

Tags: navigation

I want to switch from the Next Post/Previous Post type navigation, to showing the title of the previous or the next post.Here is the code I think needs to be changed, it's form loop-single.php

```
<nav id="nav-single">
    <h3 class="assistive-text"><?php _e( 'Post navigation', 'admired' ); ?></h3>
    <span class="nav-previous"><?php previous_post_link( '%link', __( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Previous', 'admired' ) ); ?></span>
    <span class="nav-next"><?php next_post_link( '%link', __( 'Next <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'admired' ) ); ?></span>
</nav><!-- #nav-single -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Thats WordPress [default usage](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post_link#Default_Usage).. Just remove the content within the brackets:

```
<nav id="nav-single">
    <h3 class="assistive-text"><?php _e( 'Post navigation', 'admired' ); ?></h3>
    <span class="nav-previous"><?php previous_post_link(); ?></span>
    <span class="nav-next"><?php next_post_link(); ?></span>
</nav><!-- #nav-single -->
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<nav id="nav-single">
    <h3 class="assistive-text"><?php _e( 'Post navigation', 'admired' ); ?></h3>
    <span class="nav-previous"><?php previous_post_link( '%link' ); ?></span>
    <span class="nav-next"><?php next_post_link( '%link' ); ?></span>
</nav><!-- #nav-single -->
```

That should work. next/previous post link functions have defaults for all their arguments, and the second one will default to `'%title'`, which will be replaced with the post's `post_title` property.